# Como criar máscaras de entrada em um TextField?

Tags: javafx

Há algumas semanas venho estudando o JavaFX como uma alternativa ao Swing, porém notei que ele não traz nenhum tipo de `TextField` que permita se colocar máscaras de entrada, assim como fazemos por exemplo no componente `JFormattedTextField` do Swing.

Gostaria de saber de quem desenvolve em JavaFX, como fizeram pra suprir a falta desse componente? Usaram alguma biblioteca de terceiros?

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei não há nada já "pronto". Achei [essa pergunta no GUJ](http://www.guj.com.br/13171-mascara-no-javafx) e  [esse projeto](https://github.com/davidaug/masktextfield) no Github.

Comment: Pelo que vi normalmente estão usando uma skin para contornar isso, aqui tem um exemplo para valores em dinheiro.
https://github.com/thiagofdso/MoneyTest

Comment: A quem possa interessar, também criei uma classe para atribuir mascaras em campos numéricos de forma bem simples, segue abaixo o link para o vídeo de demostração e download da classe. [Clique aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zu2F7SnoGa8&vl=pt)

Comment: Existe essa solução também [maskfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732047/how-to-apply-mask-formatting-to-textfield), funciona no fx 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente com JFX tu só tens a opção de fazer *na mão* ou pegar uma **lib** com isso.
Abaixo tem um bom ponto de partida para começar a desenvolver teu próprio componente.

```java
public abstract class MaskFieldUtil {

private static List<KeyCode> ignoreKeyCodes;

static {
    ignoreKeyCodes = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(ignoreKeyCodes, new KeyCode[]{F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11, F12});
}

public static void ignoreKeys(final TextField textField) {
    textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (ignoreKeyCodes.contains(keyEvent.getCode())) {
                keyEvent.consume();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Monta a mascara para Data (dd/MM/yyyy).
 *
 * @param textField TextField
 */
public static void dateField(final TextField textField) {
    maxField(textField, 10);

    textField.lengthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            if (newValue.intValue() < 11) {
                String value = textField.getText();
                value = value.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                value = value.replaceFirst("(\\d{2})(\\d)", "$1/$2");
                value = value.replaceFirst("(\\d{2})\\/(\\d{2})(\\d)", "$1/$2/$3");
                textField.setText(value);
                positionCaret(textField);
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Campo que aceita somente numericos.
 *
 * @param textField TextField
 */
public static void numericField(final TextField textField) {
    textField.lengthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            if (newValue.intValue() > oldValue.intValue()) {
                char ch = textField.getText().charAt(oldValue.intValue());
                if (!(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')) {
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0, textField.getText().length() - 1));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Monta a mascara para Moeda.
 *
 * @param textField TextField
 */
public static void monetaryField(final TextField textField) {
    textField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    textField.lengthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            String value = textField.getText();
            value = value.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
            value = value.replaceAll("([0-9]{1})([0-9]{14})$", "$1.$2");
            value = value.replaceAll("([0-9]{1})([0-9]{11})$", "$1.$2");
            value = value.replaceAll("([0-9]{1})([0-9]{8})$", "$1.$2");
            value = value.replaceAll("([0-9]{1})([0-9]{5})$", "$1.$2");
            value = value.replaceAll("([0-9]{1})([0-9]{2})$", "$1,$2");
            textField.setText(value);
            positionCaret(textField);

            textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                    if (newValue.length() > 17)
                        textField.setText(oldValue);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, Boolean aBoolean, Boolean fieldChange) {
            if (!fieldChange) {
                final int length = textField.getText().length();
                if (length > 0 && length < 3) {
                    textField.setText(textField.getText() + "00");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Monta as mascara para CPF/CNPJ. A mascara eh exibida somente apos o campo perder o foco.
 *
 * @param textField TextField
 */
public static void cpfCnpjField(final TextField textField) {

    textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, Boolean aBoolean, Boolean fieldChange) {
            String value = textField.getText();
            if (!fieldChange) {
                if (textField.getText().length() == 11) {
                    value = value.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                    value = value.replaceFirst("([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})$", "$1.$2.$3-$4");
                }
                if (textField.getText().length() == 14) {
                    value = value.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                    value = value.replaceFirst("([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})$", "$1.$2.$3/$4-$5");
                }
            }
            textField.setText(value);
            if (textField.getText() != value) {
                textField.setText("");
                textField.insertText(0, value);
            }

        }
    });

    maxField(textField, 18);
}

/**
 * Monta a mascara para os campos CNPJ.
 *
 * @param textField TextField
 */
public static void cnpjField(final TextField textField) {
    maxField(textField, 18);

    textField.lengthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number number2) {
            String value = textField.getText();
            value = value.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
            value = value.replaceFirst("(\\d{2})(\\d)", "$1.$2");
            value = value.replaceFirst("(\\d{2})\\.(\\d{3})(\\d)", "$1.$2.$3");
            value = value.replaceFirst("\\.(\\d{3})(\\d)", ".$1/$2");
            value = value.replaceFirst("(\\d{4})(\\d)", "$1-$2");
            textField.setText(value);
            positionCaret(textField);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Devido ao incremento dos caracteres das mascaras eh necessario que o cursor sempre se posicione no final da string.
 *
 * @param textField TextField
 */
private static void positionCaret(final TextField textField) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Posiciona o cursor sempre a direita.
            textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
        }
    });
}

/**
 * @param textField TextField.
 * @param length    Tamanho do campo.
 */
private static void maxField(final TextField textField, final Integer length) {
    textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            if (newValue.length() > length)
                textField.setText(oldValue);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Fonte: [Grupo de usuários Java](http://www.guj.com.br/13171-mascara-no-javafx)

Answer (score 6):

A quem possa interessar, desenvolvi também uma solução. Criei uma classe com funções que geram as máscaras mais comuns:

```java
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

/**
 * Funções para se aplicar máscaras aos controles do JavaFX
 * 
 * @author Paulo Henrique Luvisoto - paulobitfranca@gmail.com
 */
public class MascarasFX {

    public static void mascaraNumeroInteiro(TextField textField){

        textField.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
            if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
                textField.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
            }
        });

    }

    public static void mascaraNumero(TextField textField){

        textField.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
            newValue = newValue.replaceAll(",",".");
            if(newValue.length()>0){
                try{
                    Double.parseDouble(newValue);
                    textField.setText(newValue.replaceAll(",","."));
                }catch(Exception e){
                    textField.setText(oldValue);
                }
            }
        });

    } 

    public static void mascaraCEP(TextField textField){

        String val = "";

        textField.setOnKeyTyped((KeyEvent event) -> {
            if("0123456789".contains(event.getCharacter())==false){
                event.consume();
            }

            if(event.getCharacter().trim().length()==0){ // apagando

                if(textField.getText().length()==6){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,5));
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }

            }else{ // escrevendo

                if(textField.getText().length()==9) event.consume();

                if(textField.getText().length()==5){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText()+"-");
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }


            }
        });

        textField.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent evt) -> {

            if(!textField.getText().matches("\\d-*")){
                textField.setText(textField.getText().replaceAll("[^\\d-]", ""));
                textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
            }
        });

    }

    public static void mascaraData(TextField textField){

        textField.setOnKeyTyped((KeyEvent event) -> {
            if("0123456789".contains(event.getCharacter())==false){
                event.consume();
            }

            if(event.getCharacter().trim().length()==0){ // apagando

                if(textField.getText().length()==3){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,2));
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==6){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,5));
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }

            }else{ // escrevendo

                if(textField.getText().length()==10) event.consume();

                if(textField.getText().length()==2){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText()+"/");
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==5){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText()+"/");
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }

            }
        });

        textField.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent evt) -> {

            if(!textField.getText().matches("\\d/*")){
                textField.setText(textField.getText().replaceAll("[^\\d/]", ""));
                textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
            }
        });

    }

    public static void mascaraData(DatePicker datePicker){

        datePicker.getEditor().setOnKeyTyped((KeyEvent event) -> {
            if("0123456789".contains(event.getCharacter())==false){
                event.consume();
            }

            if(event.getCharacter().trim().length()==0){ // apagando
                if(datePicker.getEditor().getText().length()==3){
                    datePicker.getEditor().setText(datePicker.getEditor().getText().substring(0,2));
                    datePicker.getEditor().positionCaret(datePicker.getEditor().getText().length());
                }
                if(datePicker.getEditor().getText().length()==6){
                    datePicker.getEditor().setText(datePicker.getEditor().getText().substring(0,5));
                    datePicker.getEditor().positionCaret(datePicker.getEditor().getText().length());
                }

            }else{ // escrevendo

                if(datePicker.getEditor().getText().length()==10) event.consume();

                if(datePicker.getEditor().getText().length()==2){
                    datePicker.getEditor().setText(datePicker.getEditor().getText()+"/");
                    datePicker.getEditor().positionCaret(datePicker.getEditor().getText().length());
                }
                if(datePicker.getEditor().getText().length()==5){
                    datePicker.getEditor().setText(datePicker.getEditor().getText()+"/");
                    datePicker.getEditor().positionCaret(datePicker.getEditor().getText().length());
                }

            }
        });

        datePicker.getEditor().setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent evt) -> {

            if(!datePicker.getEditor().getText().matches("\\d/*")){
                datePicker.getEditor().setText(datePicker.getEditor().getText().replaceAll("[^\\d/]", ""));
                datePicker.getEditor().positionCaret(datePicker.getEditor().getText().length());
            }
        });

    }

    public static void mascaraCPF(TextField textField){

        textField.setOnKeyTyped((KeyEvent event) -> {
            if("0123456789".contains(event.getCharacter())==false){
                event.consume();
            }

            if(event.getCharacter().trim().length()==0){ // apagando

                if(textField.getText().length()==4){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,3));
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==8){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,7));
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==12){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,11));
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }

            }else{ // escrevendo

                if(textField.getText().length()==14) event.consume();

                if(textField.getText().length()==3){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText()+".");
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==7){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText()+".");
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==11){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText()+"-");
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }

            }
        });

        textField.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent evt) -> {

            if(!textField.getText().matches("\\d.-*")){
                textField.setText(textField.getText().replaceAll("[^\\d.-]", ""));
                textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
            }
        });

    }

    public static void mascaraCNPJ(TextField textField){

        textField.setOnKeyTyped((KeyEvent event) -> {
            if("0123456789".contains(event.getCharacter())==false){
                event.consume();
            }

            if(event.getCharacter().trim().length()==0){ // apagando

                if(textField.getText().length()==3){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,2));
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==7){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,6));
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==11){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,10));
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==16){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,15));
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }

            }else{ // escrevendo

                if(textField.getText().length()==18) event.consume();

                if(textField.getText().length()==2){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText()+".");
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==6){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText()+".");
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==10){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText()+"/");
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==15){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText()+"-");
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }

            }
        });

        textField.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent evt) -> {

            if(!textField.getText().matches("\\d./-*")){
                textField.setText(textField.getText().replaceAll("[^\\d./-]", ""));
                textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
            }
        });

    }

    public static void mascaraEmail(TextField textField){

        textField.setOnKeyTyped((KeyEvent event) -> {
            if("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz._-@".contains(event.getCharacter())==false){
                event.consume();
            }

            if("@".equals(event.getCharacter())&&textField.getText().contains("@")){
                event.consume();
            }

            if("@".equals(event.getCharacter())&&textField.getText().length()==0){
                event.consume();
            }
        });

    }

    public static void mascaraTelefone(TextField textField){

        textField.setOnKeyTyped((KeyEvent event) -> {
            if("0123456789".contains(event.getCharacter())==false){
                event.consume();
            }

            if(event.getCharacter().trim().length()==0){ // apagando

                if(textField.getText().length()==10&&textField.getText().substring(9,10).equals("-")){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,9));
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==9&&textField.getText().substring(8,9).equals("-")){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,8));
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==4){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,3));
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==1){
                    textField.setText("");
                }

            }else{ //escrevendo

                if(textField.getText().length()==14) event.consume();

                if(textField.getText().length()==0){
                    textField.setText("("+event.getCharacter());
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                    event.consume();
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==3){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText()+")"+event.getCharacter());
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                    event.consume();
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==8){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText()+"-"+event.getCharacter());
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                    event.consume();
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==9&&textField.getText().substring(8,9)!="-"){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText()+"-"+event.getCharacter());
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                    event.consume();
                }
                if(textField.getText().length()==13&&textField.getText().substring(8,9).equals("-")){
                    textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0,8)+textField.getText().substring(9,10)+"-"+textField.getText().substring(10,13)+event.getCharacter());
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                    event.consume();
                }

            }

        });

        textField.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent evt) -> {

            if(!textField.getText().matches("\\d()-*")){
                textField.setText(textField.getText().replaceAll("[^\\d()-]", ""));
                textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
            }
        });

    }

}
```

O código está aqui: http://pastebin.com/HNzmC2tu

Qualquer crítica ou sugestão será bem-vinda.

Comment: me ajudou muito, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Também desenvolvi uma solução que funciona quase igual ao JformmatedTextField.

Os seguintes caracteres podem ser usados:

- # : Any valid number (Character.isDigit).
- ' : Escape character, used to escape any of the special formatting characters.
- U : Any character (Character.isLetter). All lowercase letters are mapped to uppercase.
- L : Any character (Character.isLetter). All uppercase letters are mapped to lowercase.
- A : Any character or number (Character.isLetter or Character.isDigit).
- ? : Any character (Character.isLetter).
- * : Anything.
- H : Any hex character (0-9, a-f or A-F).

**Usando sem FXML:**

```
// Criando uma máscara para telefone com o placeholder padrão
MaskedTextField text = new MaskedTextField("(###)#####-####"); // Only Number

// Mudando o placeholder para espaço
text.setPlaceHolder(" ");

// Muda a máscara (Preservando o texto de acordo com a nova máscara)
text.setMask("((####))");
```

**Usando com FXML:**

```
<?import packagepath.MaskedTextField?>

<MaskedTextField mask="(###)#####-####" placeholder=" " plainText="5555"/>
```

Esta solução tem como base o código do vas7n, entretando a sistemática de inserção na máscara foi completamente reformulada. Este código inclue melhorias de legibilidade e performance, correção de bugs e inclusão todas as máscaras do JFormmatedTextField.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2017 Gustavo Fragoso
 *
 * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

package org.fxutils.maskedtextfield;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.IndexRange;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 * This approach has been inspired on https://github.com/vas7n/VAMaskField solution.
 * We added new masks, fixed bugs and improved performance.
 * Now this component works much closer to JFormattedTextfield.
 * @author gbfragoso
 */
public class MaskedTextField extends TextField{

    // Available properties
    private StringProperty mask;
    private StringProperty placeholder;
    private StringProperty plainText;

    // Available masks
    private static final char MASK_ESCAPE = '\'';
    private static final char MASK_NUMBER = '#';
    private static final char MASK_CHARACTER = '?';
    private static final char MASK_HEXADECIMAL = 'H';
    private static final char MASK_UPPER_CHARACTER = 'U';
    private static final char MASK_LOWER_CHARACTER = 'L';
    private static final char MASK_CHAR_OR_NUM = 'A';
    private static final char MASK_ANYTHING = '*';

    private ArrayList<Mask> semanticMask = new ArrayList<>();
    private int maskLength;
    private int semanticMaskLength;

    public MaskedTextField(){
        this.mask = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "mask", "");
        this.placeholder = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"placeholder","_");
        this.plainText = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"plaintext","");
        start();
    }

    public MaskedTextField(String mask){
        this.mask = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "mask", mask);
        this.placeholder = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"placeholder","_");
        this.plainText = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"plaintext","");
        start();
    }

    public MaskedTextField(String mask, char placeHolder){
        this.mask = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "mask", mask);
        this.placeholder = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"placeholder",String.valueOf(placeHolder));
        this.plainText = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"plaintext","");
        start();
    }

    // *******************************************************
    // Property's value getters
    // *******************************************************
    public final String getMask(){
        return mask.get();
    }

    public final String getPlaceholder(){
        return placeholder.get();
    }

    public final String getPlainText(){
        return plainText.get();
    }

    // *******************************************************
    // Property's value setters
    // *******************************************************
    public final void setMask(String m){
        mask.set(m);
        maskLength = m.length();
        buildSemanticMask();
        updateSemanticMask();
    }

    public final void setPlaceholder(String holder){
        placeholder.set(holder);
        resetSemanticMask();
        updateSemanticMask();
    }

    public final void setPlainText(String text){
        plainText.set(text);
        updateSemanticMask();
    }

    // *******************************************************
    // Property getters
    // *******************************************************
    public StringProperty maskProperty(){
        return mask;
    }

    public StringProperty placeholderProperty(){
        return placeholder;
    }

    public StringProperty plainTextProperty(){
        return plainText;
    }

    // *******************************************************
    // Methods
    // *******************************************************

    /**
     * Configuration method
     */
    private void start(){
        maskLength = getMask().length();
        buildSemanticMask();
        setText(allSemanticValuesToString());

        // When MaskedTextField gains focus caret goes to first placeholder position
        focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                int pos = firstPlaceholderPosition();
                selectRange(pos, pos);
                positionCaret(pos);
            });
        });
    }

    /**
     * Take user mask and convert it into a Semantic Mask, when each value receives
     * the state of literal or non-literal.
     */
    private void buildSemanticMask(){
        String newMask = getMask();
        for (int i = 0; i < maskLength; i++){
            char c = newMask.charAt(i);

            // If the actual char is MASK_ESCAPE look the next char as literal
            if(c == MASK_ESCAPE){
                semanticMask.add(new Mask(newMask.charAt(i+1), newMask.charAt(i+1), true, false));
                i++;
            }else{
                if(isLiteral(c)){
                    semanticMask.add(new Mask(c, c, true, false));
                }else{
                    semanticMask.add(new Mask(getPlaceholder().charAt(0), c, false, true));
                }
            }
        }
        semanticMaskLength = semanticMask.size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns to the initial semanticMask's state, when all non-literal values 
     * are equals to placeholder char and isPlaceholder is true.
     */
    private void resetSemanticMask(){
        char p = getPlaceholder().charAt(0);
        semanticMask.stream()
            .filter(e -> !e.isLiteral())
            .forEach(e -> {
                e.setValue(p);
                e.setPlaceholder(true);
            });
    }

    /**
     * Updates all semanticMask's values according to plainText and set the
     * editor text.
     */
    public void updateSemanticMask(){
        resetSemanticMask();

        String newPlainText = getPlainText();

        int plainCharCounter = 0;
        int plainTextSize = newPlainText.length();

        char[] textPlain = newPlainText.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < semanticMaskLength; i++){
            Mask m = semanticMask.get(i);

            // If we has free slots and plainText to add
            if(m.isPlaceholder() && plainTextSize > plainCharCounter){
                // Verifing if character entered are valid
                if(isCorrect(m.getMask(), textPlain[plainCharCounter])){

                    // Change value of mask and turn off isPlaceholder
                    m.setValue(textPlain[plainCharCounter]);
                    m.setPlaceholder(false);

                    // When MASK_LOWER|UPPER_CHARACTER is set apply lower|upper to the char
                    if(m.getMask() == MASK_LOWER_CHARACTER){
                        m.setValue(Character.toLowerCase(textPlain[plainCharCounter]));
                    }else if(m.getMask() == MASK_UPPER_CHARACTER){
                        m.setValue(Character.toUpperCase(textPlain[plainCharCounter]));
                    }

                }else{
                    // Remove wrong character from textplain
                    newPlainText = newPlainText.substring(0, plainCharCounter) + newPlainText.substring(plainCharCounter+1);
                }
                plainCharCounter++;
            }
        }

        // Setting new text with mask
        setText(allSemanticValuesToString());

        // Limiting plain text to number of free slots
        if (plainTextSize > plainCharCounter)
            newPlainText = newPlainText.substring(0, plainCharCounter);

        // If the statement above comes "true" or wrong characteres are entered, ajust the plain text
        if (!newPlainText.equals(getPlainText())){
            setPlainText(newPlainText);
        }    
    }

    /**
     * Get all the semanticMask's values and convert it into an string.
     * @return String Concatenation of all values of semanticMask
     */
    private String allSemanticValuesToString(){
        return semanticMask.stream().map(e -> String.valueOf(e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    /**
     * If a given char is literal, that is isn't a mask, return true
     * else false.
     * @param c character for verification
     * @return boolean
     */
    private boolean isLiteral(char c){
        return (c != MASK_ANYTHING &&
                c != MASK_CHARACTER &&
                c != MASK_ESCAPE &&
                c != MASK_NUMBER && 
                c != MASK_CHAR_OR_NUM &&
                c != MASK_HEXADECIMAL &&
                c != MASK_LOWER_CHARACTER &&
                c != MASK_UPPER_CHARACTER);
    }

    /**
     * For an given char and mask, returns if char is according with the mask
     * @param m An valid mask value
     * @param value Any char
     * @return boolean Return true if the given char is according with the mask
     */
    public boolean isCorrect(char m, char value){
        switch(m){
            case MASK_ANYTHING: return true;
            case MASK_CHARACTER: return Character.isLetter(value);
            case MASK_NUMBER: return Character.isDigit(value);
            case MASK_CHAR_OR_NUM: return Character.isLetterOrDigit(value);
            case MASK_HEXADECIMAL: return Pattern.matches("[0-9a-fA-F]", String.valueOf(value));
            case MASK_LOWER_CHARACTER: return Character.isLetter(value);
            case MASK_UPPER_CHARACTER: return Character.isLetter(value);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Browse semanticMask and give the position of first mask with isPlaceholder = true.
     * Even if plainText has a placeholder on it.
     * @return int first placeholder on mask
     */
    public int firstPlaceholderPosition(){
        for(int i = 0; i < semanticMaskLength; i++){
            if(semanticMask.get(i).isPlaceholder()){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Given a position in mask convert it into plainText position
     * @param pos Position in mask
     * @return converted position
     */
    private int maskPositionToPlaintextPosition(int pos){
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < semanticMaskLength && i < pos; i++){
            Mask m = semanticMask.get(i);
            if (!(m.isPlaceholder() || m.isLiteral())){
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Given a plain text position return the maskPosition
     * @param pos 
     */
    private int plaintextPositionToMaskPosition(int pos){
        int countLiterals = 0, countNonLiterals = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < semanticMaskLength && countNonLiterals < pos; i++){
            Mask m = semanticMask.get(i);
            if (m.isLiteral()){
                countLiterals++;
            }else {
                countNonLiterals++;
            }
        }

        return countLiterals + countNonLiterals;
    }

    // *******************************************************
    // Overrides
    // *******************************************************

    /**
     * Main method to insert text on mask.
     * The left side of newString only exist if user insert text on middle, is empty on most cases
     * @param start Edition's start range
     * @param end Edition's end
     * @param newText Text to be inserted/replaced
     */
    @Override
    public void replaceText(int start, int end, String newText){

        int plainStart = maskPositionToPlaintextPosition(start);

        String oldPlainText = getPlainText();
        String newString = oldPlainText.substring(0, plainStart) + newText + oldPlainText.substring(plainStart, oldPlainText.length());
        setPlainText(newString);

        int newPos = plaintextPositionToMaskPosition(newString.lastIndexOf(newText) + newText.length());
        selectRange(newPos, newPos);
    }

    /**
     * Enables the delete/insert text at selected position
     * @param string 
     */
    @Override
    public void replaceSelection(String string){
        IndexRange range = getSelection();
        if(string.equals("")){
            deleteText(range.getStart(), range.getEnd());
        }else{
            replaceText(range.getStart(), range.getEnd(), string);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete text char by char left to right (backspace) and right to left (delete)
     * @param start Delete start
     * @param end Delete end
     */
    @Override
    public void deleteText(int start, int end){

        int plainStart = maskPositionToPlaintextPosition(start);
        int plainEnd = maskPositionToPlaintextPosition(end);

        StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder(getPlainText());
        newString.delete(plainStart, plainEnd);
        setPlainText(newString.toString());

        selectRange(start, start);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(){
        setPlainText("");
    }
}
```

O código completo é um pouco grande para postar aqui, mas você pode encontrá-lo [aqui](https://github.com/gbfragoso/MaskedTextField).

Veja funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]